# Xamarin - mixing Forms and Storyboards

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uistoryboard

Is it possible to mix iOS Storyboards and Xamarin Forms within one application? I have a bunch of views that are easier to be created in Forms, but some which are heavily customized so we would need to create some of them in native code.

I would like to use Storyboards to create the native parts, but can't seem to find a way to navigate from a Forms page to a Storyboard and vice versa.

I don't mind doing it from code, just need to know the direction to look into and if it's even possible.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17865/using-xamarin-forms-alongside-storyboards

Answer (score 1):

You can create native views using the concept of Custom Renderers (see links below). The idea is that you create a Xamarin Forms Control that's shared between all platforms and which old common properties (like colors, general data etc), and do the native rendering on the iOS/Android/WP projects.

So, for your storyboard, you can create it usign Xamarin.iOS, and render using a Custom Renderer. The link posted by @GSerg in the comments have some information and examples, but you can take a closer look at the oficial documentation as well:

- [Introduction to Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/)
- [Customizing Controls on Each Platform](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)
- [Customizing Control Rendering in Xamarin.Forms (video)](https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/xamarinforms-custom-renderers/)

Also, for more real world examples you can take a look at the [Xamarin Forms XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) project.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rafael Steil's answer. I looked at the links and a few more samples.

Notably:

- [Custom Renderer Map](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map/)
- [Using Xamarin Forms alongside Storyboard](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17865/using-xamarin-forms-alongside-storyboards)

And I created a sample project to show the back-and-forth navigation between Xamarin Forms and pages created in Storyboards. You can find it over here:
[Xamarin Forms Mixed with Native](https://github.com/jasho/XamarinFormsMixedWithNative)